# How to call a WCF service in my client application form

Tags: vb.net, wcf, service

I am new to VB.NET and am completely lost on a  project. I currently have a service that contains many methods such as GetCustomersAll, GetCustomersByPhone, etc. I am now trying to consume the service with my Windows Form Application. Currently I have a service reference set up but I am just lost when it comes to programming the button in my form. I would like the button to call on the GetCustomersAll method from my service but every time I fix one error another one presents itself. So far this is the code I have:

```
Private Sub btnAllCustomers_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAllCustomers.Click
    Dim MyService As Demo2ServiceReference.Service1Client = New Demo2ServiceReference.Service1Client
    Dim MyResult As Demo2ServiceReference.Customer
    MyResult = MyService.GetCustomersAll()
    lblAllCustomers.Text = "Customer Id: " & MyResult.CustomerId & ", Customer Name: " & MyResult.FirstName & " " & MyResult.LastName & "<br/>"
End Sub
```

When I run this bit of code I get an error on "MyService.GetCustomersAll()" which says "Value of type '1-dimensional array of DemoWindowsApplication.Demo2ServiceReference.Customer' cannot be converted to 'DemoWindowsApplication.Demo2ServiceReference.Customer'.

**When I change MyResult to an array (Demo2ServiceReference.Customer()) I then get errors on my returns inside my label. MyResult.CustomerId and the rest turn into errors stating "CustomerId" is not a member of "System.Array".

This is all guess work. I honestly have no idea where to start when it comes to coding this button. If anyone has some advice or suggestions it would be much appreciated. If I have left out important information needed to assist me with this please let me know.

Comment: You should never need to directly comment on your own questions. If you have improvements to make, use the *edit* link (as I just did) (And now, please, delete your comment). To mark a block of code, highlight the block and hit the `{}` button, and it should come through nicely formatted.

Comment: (When editing, please also pay attention to the *preview* displayed below the edit box, so you can see what your question is going to look like before you actually post it)

Comment: 1. You have a WCF service, **not** a Windows service.  Those are two different things.  2. " If I have left out important information needed to assist me" - **WHAT** error(s) are you getting?  What does `GetCustomersAll` look like?  Posting your config files may help as well.  Posting a snippet of code and saying it doesn't work without giving information about the error or the behavior is like dropping your car off at the mechanic with a note saying "Please fix my car."....

Comment: Based on the error, your method is returning an array of `Customer`, so change your `MyResult`  to an array: `Dim MyResult As Deom2ServiceReference.Customer()`.

Comment: What is the purpose for `lblAllCustomers.Text`?  Do you plan on putting all the customers returned by `GetCustomersAll` in that label?  I think it would be better to use something like a `DataGridView` or some other list-type control for displaying *all* the customers.